# Europe validation expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

validation expression `ValidationExpression="\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}"` for the format is this  `ErrorMessage="Format: XXX-XXX-XXXX"`, I want the vaidatin expression to form like it can accept this europe format also of this kind `XXXX-XXXXXX` what I need to add in the above expression so that it can accept any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "or" operator (`|`)

```
"\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{4}-\d{6}"
```

---

This is a great introduction to regular expresssions if you are interested:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: There's no need for the brackets here; they just create capturing groups which won't be used. By default `|` has very low precedence so "carries" to the ends of the pattern.